# tenho de fazer o exercicio seguinte:

Tags: javascript

enunciado: Pretende-se que seja desenvolvido um programa que efectue o seguinte:
1. Pede para ler um nº N determinado de números inteiros ou não e positivos ou não, a partir do teclado;
2. Serão introduzidos esses N números, e em seguida, o programa deverá apresentar no ecrã, uma lista com as classificações seguintes:
- nº de nºs inteiros lidos
- nº de nºs fraccionários lidos
- nº de nºs negativos lidos
- nº de nºs positivos lidos
- soma dos nºs negativos lidos
- soma dos nºs positivos lidos
- média dos nºs negativos lidos
- média dos nºs positivos lidos
- soma de todos os nºs lidos
- média de todos os nºs lidos

o que eu consegui fazer:var n, soma, media, listagem;

```
        n = Number(prompt("Qual o a quantidade de números que quer introduzir?"));

        listagem = "Calculo da média dos números";
        listagem += calMedia(n);
        alert(listagem);

        function calMedia(num) {
            soma = 0;
            for(var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {             
                soma += Number(prompt(i + "º número?"));
            }
            media = soma / num;

            listagem += "\nNºs lidos: " +  num;
            listagem += "\nSoma  dos nºs lidos: " +  soma;
            listagem += "\nMédia dos nºs lidos: " +  media;
            return listagem;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
/**
         * A quantidade de números digitados é a mesma que o usuário escolheu no começo do sistema
         */
        qtd_numeros = prompt('Digite a quantidade de números');

        /*===============================================================*/
        /* Criando as variáveis para armazenar os valorres */
        /*===============================================================*/
        qtd_numeros_fracionados = 0;
        qtd_numeros_inteiros = 0;
        qtd_negativos = 0;
        qtd_positivos = 0; 
        soma_negativos = 0; 
        soma_positivos = 0; 
        media_negativos = 0;
        media_positivos = 0;
        soma_numeros = 0;
        media_numeros = 0;

        
        /*===============================================================*/
        /*
        O laço for vai executar a quantidade de
        vezes que o usuário decidiu
        */
        /*===============================================================*/

        for(x = 0; x < qtd_numeros; x++){
            var number = parseFloat(prompt('Digite o número - ' + x)); // recebe o número e converte para Float.
            if(number % 1 != 0){ // verifica se o número é fracionado
                qtd_numeros_fracionados++; // se for fracionado, aumenta 1 a quantidade de números fracionados
            }else{ // senão, esse número é inteiro
                qtd_numeros_inteiros++; // se for inteiro, aumenta 1 a quantidade de números inteiros
            }
            if(number >= 0){ // Verifica se o número é positivo
                qtd_positivos++; // se for positivo, aumenta 1 a quantidade de números positivos
                soma_positivos += number; // e e se acrescenta na soma dos números positivos
            }else{ // caso seja negativo
                qtd_negativos++; // se for negativo, acrescenta 1 a quantidade de negativos
                soma_negativos += number; // e se acrescenta na soma de negativos
            }
            soma_numeros += number; // após as verificações, ele se acrescenta na soma dos números
        }

        media_negativos = qtd_negativos > 0 ? soma_negativos / qtd_negativos : qtd_negativos; // calcula a média, caso não tenha qtd, retorna 0;
        media_positivos = qtd_positivos > 0 ? soma_positivos / qtd_positivos : qtd_positivos; // calcula a média, caso não tenha qtd, retorna 0;
        media_numeros = qtd_numeros > 0 ? soma_numeros / qtd_numeros : qtd_numeros; // calcula a média, caso não tenha qtd, retorna 0;

        
        /*===============================================================*/
        /* Adicionando os resultados aos containers criados anteriormente;*/
        /*===============================================================*/
        document.getElementById('numeros-lidos').innerHTML = 'A Quantidade de Números Digitados foram: ' + qtd_numeros;
        document.getElementById('qtd-fracionados-lidos').innerHTML = 'A Quantidade de Números Fracionados lidos foram: ' + qtd_numeros_fracionados;
        document.getElementById('qtd-inteiros-lidos').innerHTML = 'A Quantidade de Números Inteiros lidos foram: ' + qtd_numeros_inteiros;
        document.getElementById('qtd-negativos-lidos').innerHTML = 'A Quantidade de Números Negativos lidos foram: ' + qtd_negativos;
        document.getElementById('qtd-positivos-lidos').innerHTML = 'A Quantidade de Números Positivos lidos foram: ' + qtd_positivos;
        document.getElementById('soma-negativos-lidos').innerHTML = 'A Soma de Números Negativos foram: ' + soma_negativos;
        document.getElementById('soma-positivos-lidos').innerHTML = 'A Soma de Números Positivos foram: ' + soma_positivos;
        document.getElementById('media-negativos-lidos').innerHTML = 'A Média de Números Negativos foram: ' + media_negativos;
        document.getElementById('media-positivos-lidos').innerHTML = 'A Média de Números Positivos foram: ' + media_positivos;
        document.getElementById('soma-numeros-lidos').innerHTML = 'A Soma de Números Digitados foram: ' + soma_numeros;
        document.getElementById('media-numeros-lidos').innerHTML = 'A Média de Números Digitados foram: ' + media_numeros;
```

```css
*{
font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Exercicio de Javascript</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Digite os Números :)</h1>
    <!-- Criando os containers para receber as informações -->
    <div id="numeros-lidos"></div>
    <div id="qtd-fracionados-lidos"></div>
    <div id="qtd-inteiros-lidos"></div>
    <div id="qtd-negativos-lidos"></div>
    <div id="qtd-positivos-lidos"></div>
    <div id="soma-negativos-lidos"></div>
    <div id="soma-positivos-lidos"></div>
    <div id="media-negativos-lidos"></div>
    <div id="media-positivos-lidos"></div>
    <div id="soma-numeros-lidos"></div>
    <div id="media-numeros-lidos"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: mas é que precisa de ter um ciclo e n sei onde o por